# ngbPopover Doesn't Show on Hover

Tags: html, popover, ng-bootstrap

```
      <span [routerLink]="" class="icon-info" [ngbPopover]="popTemplate" triggers="" #pop="ngbPopover"
        tabindex="0" container="body" closePopoverOnClickOutside (click)="showEmail()" placement="right"></span>
```

using ng-Bootstrap (4) I am trying to make it so when I hover over an info Icon it will display relevant information. However, with the way I've set it up above the popOver doesn't show. When I check the chrome console after hover the tag shows is populated with an instance of ngbPopover but nothing shows up on screen. Any ideas where I am going wrong?
I've also tried adding it as a tooltip instead but that doesn't show either

I believe the popOver works but it is showing underneath my current dive which is a slider. Changing the z-index does nothing how can I make it appear above?

Below is the template for the popover and the showEmail() function:

```
  <ng-template #popTemplate>
  <span class="popover-close" aria-hidden="true" (click)="pop.close()">×</span>
  <p> this email. </p>
</ng-template>

  showEmail() {
    if (this.popover && this.popover.isOpen()) {
      this.popover.close();
    } else if (this.popover && !this.popover.isOpen()) {
      this.popover.open();
    }
  }
```

Comment: do you import NgbModule ?

Comment: Yes, there are other bootstrap components like modals and sliders working perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you determined whether the element appears in the DOM? You might be on the right track with `z-index`. Watch near the closing body tag.

Comment: I figured out the z-index issue it was with the parent. I have a new issue now.

Comment: Did you ever get resolution?